# How to extract photos from Firebase storage for flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I don't have a photo that should be in the background of the application, but it doesn't display anything for me, and in the error it writes something about the link

I searched for information, and I found a code that I recycled, here it is below, it is in the general class:

```
late String imageUrl;
  
final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageUrl = "";
    getImageUrl();
  }

  Future<void> getImageUrl() async {
    final ref = storage.ref().child("");
    final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      imageUrl = url;
    });
  }
```

And this is part of the code that overlays the photo on the background:

```
body: Stack(
        children: [
          Image(
            image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
          ),
)
```

Comment: You can't do this: `storage.ref().child("")`. You need to provide the path to the image in storage, not an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. **Check Firebase Storage Rules**: Ensure that your Firebase Storage rules allow public access to the images. If the rules are set to deny public access, you won't be able to fetch the image URL without proper authentication. For testing purposes, you can set the rules to allow public read access:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

2. **Check Firebase Storage Path**: In your `getImageUrl` method, you have an empty string inside `ref().child("")`. This means you're not specifying the path to the image in Firebase Storage. Make sure to provide the correct path to the image.

```dart
final ref = storage.ref().child("path/to/your/image.jpg");
```

Replace `"path/to/your/image.jpg"` with the actual path to your image in Firebase Storage.

3. **Error Handling**: Wrap your code inside try-catch blocks to catch any potential errors during fetching the image URL.

```dart
try {
  final ref = storage.ref().child("path/to/your/image.jpg");
  final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  setState(() {
    imageUrl = url;
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("Error fetching image URL: $e");
}
```

By adding error handling, you'll be able to see any errors that occur during the process, which can help in diagnosing the issue.

4. **Verify Image URL**: After obtaining the URL, print it to ensure that you're getting a valid URL.

```dart
print("Image URL: $url");
```

Check the printed URL in the console to ensure it's correct and accessible.